# rpy2 cannot find libR.so when running from PyCharm

Tags: python, r, exception, pycharm, rpy2

I think this is a very strange issue.

`import rpy2.robjects as ro` throws an `OSError` exception when running from PyCharm, but not in the python console, nor when running a python script from a terminal:

`OSError: cannot load library '/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so': libRblas.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

PyCharm is using `/usr/bin/python3.6` as is shown in project settings and the Run tab.  Here is the output of `ls -la /usr/local/lib/R/lib` :

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Aug  3 18:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 Aug  3 18:50 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   433912 Aug  3 18:50 libRblas.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  5064176 Aug  3 18:50 libRlapack.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 14251952 Aug  3 18:50 libR.so
```

My OS is Mint 19.3, I have python 3.6 and python-pip3 installed using default apt repositories, R 4.0.2 built from source as a shared library, and rpy2 installed using pip3.  With a previous R version (from apt) I had no issues using rpy2 in PyCharm.  I needed to upgrade R to 4.0.2 to use a specific package.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python, R, pip, and rpy2 multiple times.

Comment: Is terminal also using the same version? you may have edited your path....

Comment: @ameerosein: Which path should one edit? Could you post the specific "export ..." command?